# The "WHERE IN" clause SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to get a list of OpportunitiyHistory for selection of Opportunities I do:

```
   // Get all the opportunities modified in a date range.   
   List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Opportunity.OwnerId, Owner.Name 
            FROM Opportunity    
            where Opportunity.LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7];

   // Now get the corresponding history for these opportunities 
   List<OpportunityHistory> oppHistories = [SELECT Id, Probability, OpportunityID 
              From OpportunityHistory 
              where OpportunityID in:=opportunities];
```

I get:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Save error: unexpected 
     token: '='
    - unexpected token: '='
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should have: `WHERE OpportunityID in :opportunities`, at the moment you have `WHERE OpportunityID in :=opportunities`

Comment: @Joe Please post as answer .That was correct from you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:` is sufficient indication that you want to bind another variable.

```
List<OpportunityHistory> oppHistories = [SELECT Id, Probability, OpportunityID 
    From OpportunityHistory 
    where OpportunityID IN :opportunities];
```

Or even better - with one query:

```
SELECT Opportunity.OwnerId, Owner.Name,
    (SELECT Id, OldValue, NewValue FROM Histories WHERE Field = 'Probability'),
    (SELECT Id, Probability, StageName FROM OpportunityHistories)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7
```

This goes to 2 related lists, regular "field history tracking" as well as special thing available only for opportunities that tracks Probability & Stage only. Very useful if you need to have them automapped to the Opportunity.

Yet another format that wastes only 1 query:

```
SELECT Opportunity.OwnerId, Opportunity.Owner.Name, Probability, StageName
FROM OpportunityHistory 
WHERE Opportunity.LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7
ORDER BY OpportunityId, CreatedDate
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "=" from the last line and you're good.
You have `in:= list`, you need `in: list`

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder syntax doesnt need the `=` it should just be `:opportunities`

```
   // Now get the corresponding history for these opportunities 
   List<OpportunityHistory> oppHistories = [SELECT Id, Probability, OpportunityID 
              From OpportunityHistory 
              where OpportunityID in:opportunities];
```

Although if you dont need other information you can combine your queries to:

```
List<OpportunityHistory> oppHistories = [SELECT Id, OpportunityId 
    FROM OpportunityHistory 
    WHERE OpportunityId IN (
        SELECT Id 
            FROM Opportunity    
            WHERE Opportunity.LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7
    )
];
```

Comment: you don't even need the semi-join, you can do SELECT Id, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityHistory where opportunity.lastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7

Comment: I tried that in the dev console and it kept refusing to recognise the relationship, hence the sub query above :)

Comment: worked fine for me from SoqlX

Comment: I guess i must have had some typo as your right its working fine for me as well